# Browser issue with IE when working on window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, visualforce

We have a VF page named `QuoteEdit2` which opens a `SAP CRM` link in a new window.

The custom button `Create Quote` and the standard 'Edit' link of Quote object are overridden with this `QuoteEdit2` VF page. So as soon as the user creates/edits a quote (say from opportunity screen quotes related list) he is redirected to `QuoteEdit2` VF page.

The VF page is basically a blank page from UI perspective but opens a `SAP CRM` screen in a new window.

The requirement is to redirect the user back to the previous page (Opportunity page in this case).

The requirement is successfully implemented and works fine in chrome browser. But when it comes to IE browser it is not working properly.

Sample of code maintained in QuoteEdit2 vf page:

```
<script>        
    window.onLoad = new function(){                          
        var QuoteUrl = '{!QuoteUrl}';                
            childwindow = window.open(QuoteUrl,'_blank','height=' + screen.height + ',width=' + screen.width + 'channelmode=1,titlebar=1,menubar=0,location=0,toolbar=0');
            childwindow.focus(); 
            checkWindowStatus();
        }       
    function checkWindowStatus() 
    { 
        intervalId = setInterval(checkAndCloseWin, 2*1000);   
    }        
    function checkAndCloseWin() 
    { 
        if(childwindow.closed) 
        { 
           clearInterval(intervalId);
           //window.history.back(); 
           window.history.go(-1);
        } 
    }         
</script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/szBJk.png

Comment: What exactly happens in IE? Are there any messages when you open console tab from dev tools in IE?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/history - note the lack of support for what you are trying to do with IE 9 and below.

Comment: Consider type your code in your question instead of post a picture of it. Just past it, select the code and click `{}` button

Answer (score 2):

Try this `window.history.go(-1);`.

Comment: Thank you, Shimshon.I tried this. It opened the SAP CRM screen. After saving the records and closing the window, the main Opportunity/or/Quote window(my previous window) does not refresh. It remains as blank. It should bring me back to the previous window.